# Is rsync really a culprit for causing low memory on our VM?

Tags: rsync, memory, cache, buffer

In a VM of 16GB RAM, we are running rsync as a cron job(for every 10 minutes) on our production to sync GBs of folder from AWS EFS to local storage. After few days of running we found that the VM is running low on memory and we found that size of our buffer/cache is more than 4GB and using [vmtouch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465651/rsync-memory-usage) we confirmed that entire folder we are syncing is getting cached.

Since we are running this on production we have an alerting system which alerts whenever available memory in VM is less than 20%.

So as a quick fix we are clearing cache after each time rsync runs using command `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.

I'm completely against this, because clearing cache will affect the performance. But on the internet there are few articles which suggests clearing cache after running rsync jobs
some of them are [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465651/rsync-memory-usage), [2](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/rsync-hogs-memory-758345/). Also there are lot of other resources on internet which says not to clear cache.

Considering only **`rsync`**

1. Do we really need to worry about aggressive caching it is doing because of which our buff/cache is very high
2. How rest of the world is dealing with this? are you guys clearing cache each time you run rsync

rsync command we are using
`rsync -aA --delete /... /...`

Comment: cache is cache and will be freed if memory is required do not cleqn cqche like that and do not qlert on high cache uses, it's normal for linux to cache stuff but hte memory is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unused memory is wasted, so any spare memory is considered by the kernel to be available as buffer cache. It can be discarded as soon as necessary should an application need the memory.

If your entire folder is cached then that should mean that comparison between the source files and the destination files is very efficient.

The `rsync` command itself looks fine. You're not using `-H` (which can be very memory hungry), and you are usefully retaining timestamps (`-t` implied by `-a`). The only other part to be aware of is that as far as `rsync` is concerned you are copying from one part of the local filesystem to another, so files that just need to be updated will still be copied in their entirety.

Comment: `-aA` & `--delete` these are the flags I'm using, am I missing something?

Comment: we are syncing from folder `X` mounted on EFS(NFS) to another folder on local storage, are there any concern about this?

Comment: No concern. Just that rsync treats this as a local copy. You'd potentially get better efficiencies if you could run an instance of rsync on the remote server